# Running a service (script) on a site with a specified interval

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, sitecore

I have a website. the user is authorized, enters the site URL, then sets the interval in minutes (for example, 7 minutes). Then the user leaves the site.After 7 minutes, the program, the script, the service should start, I do not know how it's called and perform certain actions with the site that the user specified and then send the result to the mail. Tell me how can I do this service?What would it work even if the user came out and closed the browser. I can not understand in what direction I should move ... I use AWS from Amazon

UPD: let's describe in more detail. There is a login field, the user enters the login / password, the data is checked in a database called users, cookies are set with the user id (idUser), then the user enters one or more sites, they are stored in a database named data_ (idUser). The interval is stored in settings_ (idUser) value in the range 1-60 min. Suppose he sets the interval of 7 minutes. Then the user closes the tab, closes the browser. A specified interval (7 minutes) starts a script that takes data from the database data_ (idUser), (there are several URL sites stored there). The script processes them and sends the results of site verification to the mail. But the problem is also that the script will be one, and how to access the bd if I do not know idUser, because I can not get them from the cookie either ... Maybe I should change the database structure altogether?

Comment: The user has to write the script too or he just has to set the interval? If the script is already on your machine and the user just has to set a time for the execution you could use a web-based cron manager like cronkeep or crontab-ui.

Comment: Updated the question :)